# cvs for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, cvs

is there a place I can get just the cvs executable for OSX as a standalone binary?

I don't want to go through the whole rigamarole of having to download XCode just to get cvs, which I don't use, except the source for flickrj is only published via a cvs repository.

Comment: As of 2013-11-04, *Xcode 5 no longer includes cvs*. The easier option is using one of the package/port managers available to OSX. I'll add an answer about how to install CVS using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) below.

Comment: See also: [CVS on OS X Mavericks
 on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/cvs-on-os-x-mavericks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit]

All links below dead, and the below instructions only appear to work pre OS X Mavericks.

This [answer on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/cvs-on-os-x-mavericks) appears to solve the issue using 3rd party package managers.

[/Edit]

Not sure what happened to the other posts:

- [Version Control with CVS on Mac OSX](http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/cvsoverview.html)
- Xcode is on the DVD that came with your mac.

> 1. Boot into a partition with Mac OS X v10.5 (Leopard) installed.
> 2. Insert the Mac OS X v10.5 (Leopard) Install DVD.
> 3. Double-click the file XcodeTools.mpkg, located inside the directory Optional 
>      Installs/Xcode Tools.
>      
>    ...

ref Apple [Xcode Installation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeCoexistence/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Basics/Basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006599-CH4-SW2)

Comment: They must have restored a backup or something. It had two very different answers when I last checked. However +1 for an answer better than the ones I read in the last revision :-)

Comment: Sadly, as of Feb 2014, those are both dead links. According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/ CVS and RCS have been removed as of Xcode 5. The new official CVS web page seems to be http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/cvs

Comment: Annnnd, it turns out that it doesn't build cleanly. CVS has its own implementation of `getline()` which clashes with the one in libc. After you unpack the source code, find every reference to `getline()` and rename it to something that doesn't clash, e.g. `getlineNG()`. Then you can build it.

Comment: cvs was removed from xcode 5 on OSX 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer for OS X Mavericks+ http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/cvs-on-os-x-mavericks

Answer (score 8):

Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes # cvs is on the homebrew-dupes repository.
brew install cvs
```

See also:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/pull/201

Edit: I don't have it installed here (unfortunately I'm in a Windows machine) but yes, CVS is actually part of Homebrew core, so no need for the dupes repo, for both macOS and Linux versions of Homebrew. `brew install cvs` should be enough.

Reference:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/cvs.rb
https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/blob/master/Formula/cvs.rb

Comment: No need to tap into the dupes repo anymore, the CVS formula [has moved](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/pull/247) from homebrew-dupes to Homebrew core in November 2013.

Answer (score 2):

You could install Fink http://www.finkproject.org/download/index.php?phpLang=en then use Fink to install CVS for you, this would be the easiest way.

Alternatively, you could try a BSD binary from from the CVS project website, that *might* work. The CVS project is now at nongnu.org/cvs/

Answer (score 2):

I just learned nowadays installing xcode is a breeze.

1. Start installation of xcode from App Store
2. Have lunch
3. Type `xcrun cvs` at the command prompt and - well - enjoy cvs...

Comment: This did not work for me. "xcrun: error: unable to find utility "cvs", not a developer tool or in PATH"

Answer (score 0):

If you have xcode installed, the cvs command-line binary is in /Developer/usr/bin, so putting it your path is:

```
export PATH=/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score -1):

once Xcode is installed with commandline Utillities
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH
for newer versions of Xcode.
no moving xcode from place to place! =)